# Static attribute not shared by all Applet class instances?

Tags: java, swing, static, applet

I have an Applet subclass (a game client), all instances of which must have a reference to a single instance of another, non-applet class (dubbed `Auxillary`).
I thought this would merely be a case of declaring the attribute static, but it seems at the constructor of every applet instance, a new `Auxillary` instance is made for that Applet instance (I'm aware I'm misspelt Auxiliary all through this example...)

Here's a simple example;

**Client**

```
public class Applet extends JApplet {

    // don't yet know Auxillary constructor args
    public static Auxillary global;

    public Applet() {

        // now I know args
        if (global == null)
            global = new Auxillary("arbitrary", "arguments");

        // test global
        global.counter ++;
        System.out.println(global.counter);

    }
```

Note that I guarantee the arguments to the Auxillary constructor are/would be the same for every Applet instance.

**Auxillary**

```
public class Auxillary {

    public int counter;

    public Auxillary (Object a, Object b) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Every time I make a new Applet instance, I expect to see an increasing number printed; instead, it's constantly 1.
What am I doing wrong?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190727/why-can-multiple-applets-access-one-global-class/8190780#8190780) convinces me my Applet instances can somehow share an attribute instance.
[This Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/iac.html) demotes using the static keyword, but I interpret this for 'different instances of different Applet subclasses' (and my Applet instances will not be displayed on the same page)

So; how can I achieve it?
Thanks

Comment: Are the applets instances running in the same application?

Comment: They're Applets, so they run in their individual instances (which, as I interpret from the linked Javadoc, are in the same classloader). I'm not entirely sure, since it's at the discretion of whatever runs the Applets

Comment: My mistake; this seems to be a problem specific to running it in Eclipse; everything works fine on my server

Comment: Instead of editing the question with a *CLOSED* statement, post an answer explaining the solution to the problem. Note that this is for future readers, not only for you.

Comment: Sorry; I intend to make this 'close' tentative (since I'm still grappling with some problems. Now; the applet instances are on the user's individual computers, so don't share the static attribute)

Comment: I though you would understand that the `static` keyword just works in the same JVM, not across different JVMs.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't sure "whose" JVM was running (on the server or client's computer)

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Applet instances in the same JVM can share the static attributes (other instances are entirely separate programs...).
So, multiple tabs in a browser (like Chrome) will share the JVM and all Applet instances in these tabs will share the static attribute, but not across different browsers or machines.